# Javascript - Remove some part of URL and Add Query after

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove some part of an url and add some query before returning it?

Example:

`locahost:8080/product/orders/1.`

I want to remove the `orders/1` and add `/?query="sample"`.

Comment: I’m not sure you just need a redirect as other suggested. I mean, that link seems to be generated by something (like a form) and managed by something else (like Angular, React or Vue.js, etc.): a simple replace won’t change the base structure IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Use [replace](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-replace-method/) function:

```
location.replace("locahost:8080/product/?query='sample'")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url by simply doing `window.location.href`. You can then edit it by copying it to some new `var newURL = window.location.href;`

```
newUrl = newUrl.replace('/orders/1', '/?query=\"sample\"');

window.location.href = newUrl; // execute this to pass on the parameters to the current page.
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have url like this in variable1, let say like this

```
var variable1 = 'http://locahost:8080/product/orders/1'; //here you can get the actual browser url using `window.location.href`and assign it to `variable1`
```

just use replace function:

```
var final_text = variable1.replace('/orders/1','?query=sample');
```

you will get the following output, you do `console.log(final_text)`;

```
http://locahost:8080/product?query=sample
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
var url = window.location.href;
var query = "somestring" ;
window.location.replace(url + "&" + somestring);
```

removing the `/` pieces:

```
var newloc = url.substring(0, url.search("/")) + query;
window.location.replace(newloc);
```